# Multiple threads for optimal performance problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, performance

I've got a huge batch operation that's run every few months parsing and importing from text files into a Sql Server database. The process takes several days to complete and I'm looking at ways to speed it up a bit. Approximately 1/3 of the time is parsing the text, and 2/3 of the time in the database I/O.

I thought a simple solution would be to split these out into separate threads. So while one thread is writing to the database the other can be parsing the text. I changed the code to build up a list of SqlCommand objects that need to be executed, these are then passed to a new thread for execution once parsing is complete.

On a small sample executing the batch of SqlCommand objects in a single thread takes 37 seconds, I was then surprised when I switched to execute these in a separate thread that the process slowed down massively, taking a total of 63.34 seconds. I did some poking around and eventually decided to run some performance analysis in Visual Studio. I ran Instrumentation to measure timing on the multi threaded version and was amazed when it ran in 31.04 seconds. I reran all tests several times with more or less the same results. So it appears than when running performance analysis the splitting on the workload improves performance, but when not running performance analysis it slows down.

If anyone can help indicate what might be causing this and where I should be looking to fix it that would be fantastic!

The tests are being run in a quad core VMware virtual machine running on a 6 core host.

edit: Having looked into this further the offending lines appears to be the ones related to the parsing and nothing to do with the DB, mainly fileText.Trim(). Why these should run much slower with the debugger attached I have no idea.

**Code the launches the new thread**

```
        while (sqlWriterThread != null && sqlWriterThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        if (sqlWriterThread == null || sqlWriterThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
            sqlWriterThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SqlWriterThread));
            sqlWriterThread.Name = "SqlWriterThread";
            sqlWriterThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        }
        sqlWriterThread.Start(commandBatch);
        Thread.Sleep(0);
```

**Query Execution Code**

```
    public void SqlWriterThread(object commandBatch)
    {
        List<SqlCommand> batch = (commandBatch as List<SqlCommand>);
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(HelperDatabase.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                foreach (SqlCommand cmd in batch)
                {
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the .net framework version you are using?

Comment: Were you running with the debugger attached when you timed the 63.34 seconds? Hit ctrl+f5 to run without the debugger, vs just pressing f5 which will run with the debugger attached, which will slow down performance

Comment: @BrandonAGr - That seems to have solved the issue. If you post that as an answer then I'll mark it as answered. That doesn't explain why running multiple threads with the debugger attached should run at half the speed of just running a single thread. That's the real mystery here.

Answer (score 1):

As with any SQL Server performance problem, I recommend using [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) methodology. This will narrow down the problem to where the actual wait/contention/bottleneck occurs.

One cannot say much w/o any further data, and in lack of any specific SQL info in your post: what are those sqlCommands in your batchs? Is it a heap? Is it a btree? How mny secondary indexes? Exact definition of the schema, exact database file location and spindles distribuution, you know, the *basic* information.

Comment: The DB is on an SSD, so no spindles. I'll work out what other info I can include in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

You are separate the execution of synchronous operation to asynchronous mode, while other thread(s) probably running at the same time which cause the operation to execute in longer time.

However that will not be the case if you are separate the other parts to threads, so you will get the benefits from multithreading in that case. i.e: the "parsing the text" in a thread, "database I/O in another thread", and also separate the work inside the threads to more chunks "threads" if applicable.

If you are running `4.0` I suggest you to use `Parallel.ForEach` for executing the code inside the D.B thread:

```
Parallel.ForEach(batch => cmd
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
});
```

Comment: The Parallel.ForEach wont work because only one command can be executed per transaction and per connection at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is inherently broken if it takes days. Are you procssing one record at a time? try a bulk insert to a staging table, then using SQl to celan up the data and then a set-based process to insert the data (you may want to loop in batches of several thousand at once if the files are huge).

Or create an SSIS package to do the loading for you.

Comment: It's parsing 1 chunk of text at a time, it's not a simple parse process. The required records are then created and inserted relating to that one chunk of text.

Comment: I do complex transformations all the time but do it in a set-based fashion. I've imported more than 20 million records in less than an hour.

Comment: It's not just importing data, it's reading, writing and updating what's already there based on many thousands of lines of code creating various rules. 200m+ records created in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping a number of commands in a batch transaction managed at the client-side.  What kind of commands are they?

If the transactions were simple inserts, I would wonder about just writing a file out and using BCP/SSIS, but I imagine it's much more complex than that.

If it's multiple parent-child inserts (which is why you are using a transaction - although I see no indication of this, because you do not seem to be saving a parent ID for children creation), could this possibly be done with a table-valued parameter to a stored proc which does the entire transaction in a single call - begin transaction insert parent, insert children, commit transaction?